# Creating an excel file in java

Tags: java

I am using SpringFramework. I want to create an excel file using Java.
Below is the code in which i failed creating a excel file.

```
public  void eventsUpdate(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=events123.xls");

        HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Answer (score 1):

I would sugges you take a look at: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html